# TypeError: this.syncService.getShops(...).valueChanges is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

Getting a "TypeError: this.syncService.getShops(...).valueChanges is not a function" error but I can't seem to figure out why. Does it have something to do with my `getShops()` function? `getShops` returns an array of shops objects. As far as I can tell this shouldn't be a problem. New to angular and I'm trying to make my ionic searchbar work on a list of shops.

Typescript

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolbarTitleService } from '../Services/toolbar-title.service';
import { IonSearchbar, PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PopoverComponent } from '../popover/popover.component';
import { SyncServiceService } from '../Services/sync-service.service';
import { UserService } from '../Services/user.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-locaties',
  templateUrl: './locaties.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./locaties.component.css'],
})
export class LocatiesComponent implements OnInit {
  public locations: any[] = [];
  user;
  public locationsBackup: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private toolbarTitle: ToolbarTitleService,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    private syncService: SyncServiceService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.toolbarTitle.setToolbarTitle('Locaties');
    this.user = await this.userService.getUser();
    // Haalt alle shops van de gebruiker op en zet ze in locations
    this.locations = await this.syncService.getShops(this.user);
    this.locations = await this.initializeItems();
  }

  // Popover
  async presentPopover(ev: any, Contact: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      componentProps: {
        phones: Contact.Phones[0].Number,
        email: Contact.Email,
        street: Contact.Addresses[0].Street1,
        city: Contact.Addresses[0].City,
      },
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }

  // Search
  async initializeItems(): Promise<any> {
    this.locations = await this.syncService
      .getShops(this.user)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(first())
      .toPromise();
    this.locationsBackup = this.locations;
    return this.locations;
  }

  // Filter
  async filterList(evt) {
    this.locations = this.locationsBackup;
    const searchTerm = evt.srcElement.value;

    if (!searchTerm) {
      return;
    }

    this.locations = this.locations.filter((currentLocation) => {
      if (currentLocation.Name && searchTerm) {
        return (
          currentLocation.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) >
          -1
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `getShops` return an array of shops objects or an observable of array of shops objects?

Comment: @Krantisinh just an array of shops objects

Comment: Array does not have `valuechanges` function on it. Hence the error. valuechanges is a function on angular reactive form provided by angular so that you can react to changes in form. On normal arrays, there's no such thing.

Comment: @Krantisinh I'm not sure I understand.. How would I be able to fix it? How would I be able to give my array the `valuechanges` function?

Comment: From what I can infer from your code, you need `valuechanges` to detect the first value change. So, if you return an observable of array from the getshops method instead of just an array, you'll be able to get the first of the emitted value and ignore the rest.

Comment: `this.syncService.getShops(this.user).pipe(first()).toPromise()`

Comment: Alright, I tried to return an observable array from getShops() by using RxJS `from()` but it didn't work. "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231522/discussion-between-furkan-ozturk-and-krantisinh).